# How to get feature names of shap_values from TreeExplainer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, shap

I am doing a shap tutorial, and attempting to get the shap values for each person in a dataset

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import xgboost
import shap
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

X,y = shap.datasets.adult()
X_display,y_display = shap.datasets.adult(display=True)

# create a train/test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=7)
d_train = xgboost.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
d_test = xgboost.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)
params = {
    "eta": 0.01,
    "objective": "binary:logistic",
    "subsample": 0.5,
    "base_score": np.mean(y_train),
    "eval_metric": "logloss"
}
#model = xgboost.train(params, d_train, 5000, evals = [(d_test, "test")], verbose_eval=100, early_stopping_rounds=20)

xg_clf = xgboost.XGBClassifier()
xg_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(xg_clf, X_train)
#shap_values = explainer(X)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)
```

going through the Python3 interpreter, `shap_values` is a massive array of 32,561 persons, each with a shap value for 12 features.

For example, the first individual has the following SHAP values:

```
>>> shap_values[0]
array([ 0.76437867, -0.11881508,  0.57451954, -0.41974955, -0.20982443,
       -0.38079952, -0.00986504,  0.32272505, -3.04392116,  0.00411322,
       -0.26587735,  0.02700199])
```

However, which value applies to which feature is a complete mystery to me.

the documentation says:

```
For models with a single output this returns a matrix of SHAP values
        (# samples x # features). Each row sums to the difference between the model output for that
        sample and the expected value of the model output (which is stored in the expected_value
        attribute of the explainer when it is constant). For models with vector outputs this returns
        a list of such matrices, one for each output
```

When I go to `explainer` which produced `shap_values` I see that I can get feature names:

```
explainer.data_feature_names
['Age', 'Workclass', 'Education-Num', 'Marital Status', 'Occupation', 'Relationship', 'Race', 'Sex', 'Capital Gain', 'Capital Loss', 'Hours per week', 'Country']
```

but I cannot see how to get feature names within shap_values at the Python interpreter, if they're even there:

```
>>> shap_values.
shap_values.all(           shap_values.compress(      shap_values.dump(          shap_values.max(           shap_values.ravel(         shap_values.sort(          shap_values.tostring(
shap_values.any(           shap_values.conj(          shap_values.dumps(         shap_values.mean(          shap_values.real           shap_values.squeeze(       shap_values.trace(
shap_values.argmax(        shap_values.conjugate(     shap_values.fill(          shap_values.min(           shap_values.repeat(        shap_values.std(           shap_values.transpose(
shap_values.argmin(        shap_values.copy(          shap_values.flags          shap_values.nbytes         shap_values.reshape(       shap_values.strides        shap_values.var(
shap_values.argpartition(  shap_values.ctypes         shap_values.flat           shap_values.ndim           shap_values.resize(        shap_values.sum(           shap_values.view(
shap_values.argsort(       shap_values.cumprod(       shap_values.flatten(       shap_values.newbyteorder(  shap_values.round(         shap_values.swapaxes(      
shap_values.astype(        shap_values.cumsum(        shap_values.getfield(      shap_values.nonzero(       shap_values.searchsorted(  shap_values.T              
shap_values.base           shap_values.data           shap_values.imag           shap_values.partition(     shap_values.setfield(      shap_values.take(          
shap_values.byteswap(      shap_values.diagonal(      shap_values.item(          shap_values.prod(          shap_values.setflags(      shap_values.tobytes(       
shap_values.choose(        shap_values.dot(           shap_values.itemset(       shap_values.ptp(           shap_values.shape          shap_values.tofile(        
shap_values.clip(          shap_values.dtype          shap_values.itemsize       shap_values.put(           shap_values.size           shap_values.tolist(
```

**My primary question**: How can I figure out which feature in

`['Age', 'Workclass', 'Education-Num', 'Marital Status', 'Occupation', 'Relationship', 'Race', 'Sex', 'Capital Gain', 'Capital Loss', 'Hours per week', 'Country']`

applies to which number in each row of `shap_values`?

```
>>> shap_values[0]
array([ 0.76437867, -0.11881508,  0.57451954, -0.41974955, -0.20982443,
       -0.38079952, -0.00986504,  0.32272505, -3.04392116,  0.00411322,
       -0.26587735,  0.02700199])
```

I would assume that the features are in the same order, but I have no evidence for that.

My secondary question: how can I find the feature names in `shap_values`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The features are indeed in the same order, as you assume; see [how to extract the most important feature names?](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/632#issuecomment-499680372) and [how to get feature names from explainer](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/658#issuecomment-505055414) issues in Github.

To find the feature name, you simply need to access the element with the same index of the array with the names

For example:

```py
shap_values = np.array([
    0.76437867, -0.11881508,  0.57451954, -0.41974955, -0.20982443,
   -0.38079952, -0.00986504,  0.32272505, -3.04392116,  0.00411322,
   -0.26587735,  0.02700199])
features_names = ['Age', 'Workclass', 'Education-Num', 'Marital Status', 'Occupation',
                  'Relationship', 'Race', 'Sex', 'Capital Gain', 'Capital Loss',
                  'Hours per week', 'Country']

features_names[shap_values.argmin()]  # the index 8 -> Capital Gain
features_names[shap_values.argmax()]  # the index 0 -> Age
```

Comment: [This answer](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/632#issuecomment-823923453) in the first link you posted works great.

Answer (score 2):

If you find this answer useful, upvote [@lucas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67444552/8162025) and GitHub user ba1mn's [post](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/632#issuecomment-823923453). I'm just adding it here in case the link breaks.

The following function will return the feature names along with their corresponding importance in a DataFrame.

```py
def global_shap_importance(model, X):
    """ Return a dataframe containing the features sorted by Shap importance
    Parameters
    ----------
    model : The tree-based model 
    X : pd.Dataframe
         training set/test set/the whole dataset ... (without the label)
    Returns
    -------
    pd.Dataframe
        A dataframe containing the features sorted by Shap importance
    """
    explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
    shap_values = explainer(X)
    cohorts = {"": shap_values}
    cohort_labels = list(cohorts.keys())
    cohort_exps = list(cohorts.values())
    for i in range(len(cohort_exps)):
        if len(cohort_exps[i].shape) == 2:
            cohort_exps[i] = cohort_exps[i].abs.mean(0)
    features = cohort_exps[0].data
    feature_names = cohort_exps[0].feature_names
    values = np.array([cohort_exps[i].values for i in range(len(cohort_exps))])
    feature_importance = pd.DataFrame(
        list(zip(feature_names, sum(values))), columns=['features', 'importance'])
    feature_importance.sort_values(
        by=['importance'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
    return feature_importance
```