# How to get feature importances/feature ranking from summary plot in SHAP without crashing?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, shap

I am attempting to get shap values out of an array which was created by

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(xg_clf, X_train)
shap_values2 = explainer(X_train)
```

using my XGBoost data, to make a dataframe of feature_names and their SHAP importance, as they would appear in a SHAP bar or summary plot.

Following advice from [how to extract the most important feature names?](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/632) and [How to get feature names of shap_values from TreeExplainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443411/how-to-get-feature-names-of-shap-values-from-treeexplainer) specifically the comment by user Thoo, which shows how the values can be extracted to make a dataframe:

```
vals= np.abs(shap_values).mean(0)
feature_importance = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(X_train.columns,vals)),columns=['col_name','feature_importance_vals'])
feature_importance.sort_values(by=['feature_importance_vals'],ascending=False,inplace=True)
feature_importance.head()
```

shap_values has 11595 persons with 595 features each, which I understand is large, but, creating the `vals` variable runs very slowly, about 58 minutes on my laptop. It uses almost all RAM on the computer.

After 58 minutes I get an error:
`Command terminated by signal 9`

which as far as I understand, means that the computer ran out of RAM.

I've tried converting the 2nd line in Thoo's code to

```
feature_importance = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(X_train.columns,np.abs(shap_values2).mean(0))),columns=['col_name','feature_importance_vals'])
```

so that `vals` isn't stored but this change doesn't reduce RAM at all.

I've also tried a different comment from the same GitHub issue (user "ba1mn"):

```
def global_shap_importance(model, X):
    """ Return a dataframe containing the features sorted by Shap importance
    Parameters
    ----------
    model : The tree-based model 
    X : pd.Dataframe
         training set/test set/the whole dataset ... (without the label)
    Returns
    -------
    pd.Dataframe
        A dataframe containing the features sorted by Shap importance
    """
    explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
    shap_values = explainer(X)
    cohorts = {"": shap_values}
    cohort_labels = list(cohorts.keys())
    cohort_exps = list(cohorts.values())
    for i in range(len(cohort_exps)):
        if len(cohort_exps[i].shape) == 2:
            cohort_exps[i] = cohort_exps[i].abs.mean(0)
    features = cohort_exps[0].data
    feature_names = cohort_exps[0].feature_names
    values = np.array([cohort_exps[i].values for i in range(len(cohort_exps))])
    feature_importance = pd.DataFrame(
        list(zip(feature_names, sum(values))), columns=['features', 'importance'])
    feature_importance.sort_values(
        by=['importance'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
    return feature_importance
```

but `global_shap_importance` returns the feature importances in the wrong order, and I don't see how I can alter `global_shap_importance` so that the features are returned in the same order as `summary_plot` (beeswarm plot).

How can I get the feature importance ranking into a dataframe?

Comment: Try a 1/10th random sample.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled this straight from the source code. Confirmed identical to the summary_plot.

```py
def shapley_feature_ranking(shap_values, X):
    feature_order = np.argsort(np.mean(np.abs(shap_values), axis=0))
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "features": [X.columns[i] for i in feature_order][::-1],
            "importance": [
                np.mean(np.abs(shap_values), axis=0)[i] for i in feature_order
            ][::-1],
        }
    )
```

Comment: If called on shapley_feature_ranking(shap_values, X)
`features importance
0 Index(['feature_271', 'feature_239', 'feature_... [[0.0025582758, 0.0012526097, 0.0028011668, 0....
1 Index(['feature_144', 'feature_136', 'feature_... [[0.0024217064, 0.0016129484, 0.0066467705, 0....`
if called on shapley_feature_ranking(shap_values[0], X)
gives the wrong order

Answer (score 0):

More utilization of numpy will save much of computational time

```
def get_shap_ranking(shap_values,
                     X:pd.DataFrame)->list:
    '''For multiclass'''
    shap_values_aggregated = np.stack(shap_values, 
                                      axis=2)  # last dim number is equal to number of classes

    # Calculate the absolute sum across observations for each feature and class
    abs_sum_per_feature_class = np.abs(shap_values_aggregated).sum(axis=(0, 2))  # (310,)

    # Calculate the mean absolute sum across features
    mean_abs_sum_per_feature = abs_sum_per_feature_class.mean()

    # Create a dictionary mapping feature names to mean absolute sum values
    feature_abs_sum_dict = {feature_name: abs_sum for feature_name, abs_sum in zip(data.columns, abs_sum_per_feature_class)}

    # Sort features based on mean absolute sum values
    sorted_features = sorted(feature_abs_sum_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    return sorted_features
```

The order is the same as in the plot and the values are proportional to the width of corresponding rows in the plot.

You can then to dataframe with

```
pd.DataFrame(sorted_features, columns=["feature", "importance"])
```